# how do i change date format in python using datetime

Tags: python, date, format

I'm still new to python, looking for suggestion regarding my problem.
I have a date format like this: **January 13 2022**
I need to convert it to: **13-Jan-22**
the date is located in a pandas data frame called df in cell ['Date'][0]
I tried this code:

```
df['Date'][0] = df['Date'][0].strftime(df['Date'][0], '%B %d %Y')

df['Date'][0].strftime('%d-%b-%Y')
```

df
but got this error message instead

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'
```

any suggestion?

Comment: Can you add a code example of how you're currently trying to do this?

Comment: You may want to start by showing exactly what code you are using, and what error you get, as it is reported, not reformulated. Your task needs two parts: parsing the string you have to get a native `datetime` object, and then formatting this object back to a string with a different format you need. Which parts did you do, which give you problems?

Comment: Please read and supply an [mre].

Comment: hi, added the code already